# Highest number of consecutively repeating values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have this list:

```
List= [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

How do I display the highest number of repeating 1s in a row?
I want to return 5.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Is the list always going to contain only 1s and 0s?

Comment: Actually, I'm still a beginner and I have no idea what to try. And no it won't necessarily contain zeros and ones, any 2 repeating values

Comment: so you want the highest number of consecutive elements in list? Am I right?

Comment: If you have no idea you should first do some research and try something and post some code before asking for a solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: I did the research and came up with no result

Comment: Mouse on the Keys.. Thank you so much

Comment: @user112279644 no problems just next time be more specific with defining your question please, read help section how to ask question, and help us to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t really understand the question, but if you want the highest number of consecutive elements in list, maybe something like this

```py
from itertools import groupby

list = [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
count_cons_val = [sum(1 for _ in group) for _, group in groupby(list)]
print(max(count_cons_val))
```

**Output:**

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Find my comments how this answer helps you out inline after the `#` tag.

```
save = None
count = 0
best = 0
for i in list:
    if i == save:
        count += 1 # if it's the same as last add 1 to count
        best = count
    else: #if it is different reset with the new element
        count = 0
        save = i

print(best)
```